# How to save worksheets to different specific folders based on worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to save the worksheets in a workbook to specified folder locations.

The conditions will be based on the worksheet name based on this example table in one of the worksheet in the current workbook. There is a possibility to add on to the naming conventions table..

[image: table]

*assume the folders are located in the same path as current workbook.

Currently i only have this code, which is saving to current path..

```
Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
 Dim NewBook As Workbook, OldBook As Workbook, sh As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    Set OldBook = ThisWorkbook

    For Each sh In OldBook.Worksheets
        If sh.Visible = True Then
            sh.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OldBook.Path & "\" & sh.Name, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is in a sheet named "MainSheet" and the folders specified in column C are inside the current path, the following might work. You should add errors handlers, for example in the case that the folder or the sheets specified in your table do not exist.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    Dim OldBook As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim TheSheetToSave As String, TheFileName As String, TheFilePath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set OldBook = ThisWorkbook
    'Find last row of table
    LastRow = OldBook.Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Scan all rows of table
    For i = 2 To LastRow 'Start in second row. First row for titles
        TheSheetToSave = OldBook.Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value
        TheFileName = OldBook.Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i, 2).Value
        TheFilePath = OldBook.Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i, 3).Value

        Worksheets(TheSheetToSave).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OldBook.Path & "\" & TheFilePath & "\" & TheFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
Was just wondering if this is the preferred method to do the lookup? Meaning that the table values is used as the source to match against the worksheet names, instead of the other way round.

Comment: Writing the sheet names in a table has the problem that you must assure that the sheet exists, so I would go with your proposal. The problem is to set the folder, for which I would go with the table. I think I would go with your code (`For each sh`), look for the sheet name in the table, and if the name exists select the folder. If sheet nema do not exist, assign a folder like `NotDefined`, so you can check.